# Is it Possible to run VB 6 in visual studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vb6

I have some doubts related to Vb 6.

1. I want to create an VB 6 application and very much familiar with visual studio.
   So can I use Visual studio as a editor instead of VB 6 editor.
2. Can I use dll in vb 6. So I can cover maximum code in C#.

Please let me know your suggestions regarding this.

Thanks

Comment: no. even importing vb6 project is not possible

Comment: Why not code the whole project in C#? Do you need to hook into some *existing* VB6 code? VB6 can be a client for C# code if you create an ActiveX DLL in VB6, and add a reference in the COM tab on the C# project references dialogue. C# can be a client for VB6 code if you create a COM-visible DLL, and add a reference in the VB6 project components dialogue.

Answer (score 2):

No.

1 - Due to the syntax changes between VB.NET and VB6 the editor will not work. For example if you write:

`Set Foo=Bar` the VB.NET editor will remove the `Set`.

2 - Yes you can use a VB6 DLL in a C# or VB.NET project this should be not issue, but you wont be able to edit or compile it is Visual Studio.

Note:
You used to be able to 'convert' VB6 apps in Visual Studio Version prior to 2010 by using the [Visual Studio Upgrade Wizard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0zc22a8x%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), but that feature is not available anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Note that you can debug VB6 code in Visual Studio, when the `.pdb` files are available, but the code will be seen as VB.NET code by the syntax display. You just need to turn on "native" debugging.